# what is the difference between gdb and gdb-peda?

Tags: 20.04, c++, c, debugging, gdb

I have tried to search on google but still could not find anything that i understand.

Can anyone tell me the difference between them?
And which one is better to debug c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEDA means “Python<sup>1</sup> Exploit Development Assistance for GDB” [according to its developer](https://github.com/longld/peda). It is an *extension* for the standard [GDB](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdb&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (which can be installed using APT on Ubuntu). So even for using PEDA, you have to install GDB first.

[PEDA’s GitHub page](https://github.com/longld/peda) offers a list of key features. If anything there is interesting for you, you can try installing it. If not, you can most likely stick with the standard GDB.

---

<sup>1</sup> Python is the language in which PEDA is implemented. This does not say anything regarding usability for a particular programming language.